# Cannot override bootstrap variables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to override Bootstrap colors, following the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults), but nothing changes.

I'm using `react-bootstrap@2` and `bootstrap@5`

Here is my root sass file:

```
// Presence of these two imports doesn't make a difference
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables"; // Moving this line under the custom variables also doesn't work

$primary: #222;

$theme-colors: (
    primary: #222,
);

// Tried map-merge, no effect
// $theme-colors: map-merge(
//  $theme-colors,
//  (
//      primary: #222,
//  )
// );

$white: #000;
$black: #fff;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I've looked up at many answers of similar problems but none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact setup and file composition:

- Create for example an App.scss file
- Define your variable overrides
- Import bootstrap in the end
- Import this .scss file in your upper component, i.e. App.jsx

  $primary: red;

  /* import bootstrap to set changes */
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-drake-3cevf3

Comment: This is what I did, the file is imported in my `index.tsx`. The import works since other styles show properly

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example then. Your code above is not sufficient. As you can see everything works in the sandbox. So the question is: what is different in your setup?